# Is it possible to make visible vertical scrollbar for single row in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer, vertical-scrolling

I have a DataGrid with single row. I want to scroll the content inside the DataGrid. I have used following way to do it.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MaxHeight="250">
     <DataGrid  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxWidth="800" Grid.Row="1"/>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

As I am using ScrollViewer outside the datagrid, it scrolls whole datagrid. I want to scroll content inside row by enabling vertical scrollbar for a single row. Is this possible?

Comment: ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" set on DataGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `ScrollViewer`, `DataGrid` has got its own `Scrollviewer` builtin.
Set

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

or

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

in your `DataGrid`

Comment: Auto will not work if  the width of row is expands. Fix it

Comment: Here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll(v=vs.110).aspx) it is documented as  'If you require physical scrolling instead of logical scrolling, wrap the host Panel element in a ScrollViewer and set its CanContentScroll property to false. Physical scrolling is the default scroll behavior for most Panel elements.' I guess that's why ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" is working for me

Comment: "As I am using ScrollViewer outside the datagrid, it scrolls whole datagrid". I intended as you don't want physical scrolling. do you want that any row has got its own scrollbar? if yes i don't think datagrid is the best choice

Comment: rmbq posted correct answer. It should work, unless you have explicitly templated DataGrid and the template itself is messed up. Anyway if you want to have a different scrollbar in every cell, it is possible as well, just define cell template to be wrapped in scroll bar. I wouldn't be the happiest person on the Earth if I'd have to use this solution as an end user tho...

Comment: @rmbq I think you are right !! Its working because I have only one row in datagrid. For multiple rows physical scrolling wont be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @KacperStachowski Thanks. May be templating DataGrid explicitely is the reason rmbq's solution not working for me. Your suggestion may solve my issue.